# java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class. Code working fine in debug mode, but not throwing this error in release mode

Tags: java, android, proguard, jwi

Please help on this error.Below is error logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class edu.mit.jwi.morph.SimpleStemmer: java.util.List edu.mit.jwi.morph.SimpleStemmer.getNounCollocationRoots(java.lang.String) failed to verify: java.util.List edu.mit.jwi.morph.SimpleStemmer.getNounCollocationRoots(java.lang.String): [0x50] register v6 has type Reference: java.lang.Object but expected Precise Reference: java.lang.String

     java.util.List edu.mit.jwi.morph.SimpleStemmer.getVerbCollocationRoots(java.lang.String) failed to verify: java.util.List edu.mit.jwi.morph.SimpleStemmer.getVerbCollocationRoots(java.lang.String): [0x60] register v7 has type Reference: java.lang.Object but expected Precise Reference: java.lang.String
```

Comment: Please post some code and let us know what portion of your code leads to this error.

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue, I was using

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
```

I degraded the corountine to

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6'
```

and it worked.

It seems version 1.3.9 has some bugs according to [kotlin documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2049)

Answer (score 3):

If it happend to coroutines on Android, revert coroutines lib to 1.3.6 works for me.
It seems that there is VerifyError bug in android coroutines lib version 1.3.7-1.3.8, and fixed after 1.4.0.

Details see below link:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2049
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2041

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading dependencies did not work for me.

### Remove `@JvmStatic`

If you create a suspend function be sure that you are not also using the `@JvmStatic` annotation for this method.
Doing so will definitely throw this error.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
This was an unnecessary issue thrown after the use of Proguard.

Added -dontwarn for that class in the Proguard rules. The release is working perfectly fine.