# Superclass androidx.core.app.f of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity is declared final

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I wanted to update the version of the application in the Play Store, but in the tests I started getting this error.

```
Superclass androidx.core.app.f of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity is declared final
```

According to the [google issues tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785592) this is new, maybe someone has a solution to this problem.

Comment: This seems to be only happening in pre-launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 27.07.2022 Google team members posted that the bug has been fixed.
and on 09.08.2022 they added some explanation that you can find in this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785592).

In two words:
In pre-launch testing app-crawler apk and the app apk generated different ‘keep rules’ for shrunk.
This will cause ‘no such method’ or ‘superclass will be declared final’.

Answer (score 8):

I added

```
-keep class androidx.core.app.** { *; }
```

In the proguard rules to solve the issue.

Edit: minus sign (-) needs to be before the line

Comment: Have you understood what the problem is exactly? Is it a specific version of an AndroidX library?

Comment: I'm following this thread https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785592

Comment: Wouldn't `-keep class androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity { *; }` be enough in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade some libraries in your `build.gradle`?

**Coroutines** maybe?

We have this exception reported too and it has the same stack trace as an older exception we had before, so possibly equally related to the Kotlin coroutines lib version:

[java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class. Code working fine in debug mode, but not throwing this error in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59113152/java-lang-verifyerror-verifier-rejected-class-code-working-fine-in-debug-mode)

Comment: HI, not I didn't update gradle or coroutines. On all local devices it works fine, but on google test devices it crashes. Also according to firebase-crashlytics it crashed several times while google testing.

Answer (score 1):

You try update implementation 'com.google.android.gms' in build.gradle to lastest version

Comment: Hi, it's the last version and also I didn't make any changes to it in the last release.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Flutter. I  remove Firebase from build.gradle

// implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')

also downgrading firebase to 29.0.2 is working too.

Comment: My project currently uses 26.0.0, so it's not the case

Answer (score 1):

I added this line into gradle.properties

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=true
```

I hope it will help you too

Answer (score 0):

### For builds made before August 2022

If your APK/App Boundle was created before August 2022, the issue might be related to an internal issue by Google.

See this issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237785592?pli=1

For me it was enough to build a new release on my machine (increasing version number at least by 1!) and upload it... Afterwards, the problem was gone.